# How do I put a global dynamic prefix in a razor core route?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a razor application in .NET 7, and I am looking to add a dynamic route prefix to all my pages.  This is seemingly trivial in Web API and MVC; however, I have not been able to crack this in razor.

Desired input:
[http://somesite.com/{siteName}/{*pageAndQueryString?}](http://somesite.com/%7BsiteName%7D/%7B*pageAndQueryString?%7D)

Desired output:
/pages/{pageAndQuerystring} (with siteName in routedata)

Bonus if I can do this for every directory/page in one page route.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, based on further digging, I needed to create a Route Model Convention:

```
public class CustomRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        List<SelectorModel> selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = $"/{{SiteName}}/{template}"
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var m in selectorModels)
        {
            model.Selectors.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

which could then be applied, as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new CustomRouteModelConvention());
});
```

This seems to get me 99% of the way there.  I've been on this for two days, but got hung up, because at some point I had accidentally removed "app.MapRazorPages()"